# How to change the height of just one nodepart in TikZ?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I want to change the height of one part of the node to the minimum possible. How can I do this?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[rectangle split,rectangle split parts=3] {
      first
      \nodepart{second}
      \nodepart{third}
      third
    };
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I want the second part (which is empty) to be 0.1cm in height.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the key `rectangle split empty part height` to set the height of empty parts. However, this key only adds a a invisible rule with the given height to an internal macro. Therefore the height can't be reduced once set. The default value is 1ex. The overwrite this use the key `rectangle split every empty part={}` which deletes all previous set height, depth and width values.

The `inner sep` value is still added around the empty part which makes it very difficult to make it smaller without reducing this value.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[rectangle split,rectangle split parts=3,draw] {
      XgX
      \nodepart{second}
      \nodepart{third}
      XgX
    };
  \end{tikzpicture}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[rectangle split,rectangle split parts=3,inner sep=0pt,
    rectangle split every empty part={},% delete existing height, depth and width
    rectangle split empty part height=0.1cm,
    draw] {
      XgX
      \nodepart{second}%
      \nodepart{third}
      XgX
    };
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: this is what LaTeX processor says: `Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/tikz/rectangle split every empty part' and I am going to ignore it. Perhaps you misspelled it.` Any ideas?

Comment: @yegor256: Yes, update your TikZ/PGF package. Your seems to be outdated.